# ProgrammingError i can't use my database in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I get this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'payroll'
```

when goto to cmd and mysql i see my database

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| payroll            |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> USE payroll
Database changed
```

what error?

my code:

```
import mysql.connector

mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="126332",database="payroll")
mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()
```

Comment: Please, show your code

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? And why have you tagged [tag:oracle]?

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database server?

Comment: mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="126332",database="payroll")
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()