# Create my database in python but i can't find it

Tags: python, jquery, mysql, database, command

I create my database with python

```
    import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="126332"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")
```

but after goto cmd and mysql 8.0 command Line and run this command

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASEs;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| payroll            |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.28 sec)
```

but i can't see my database "mydatabase"

where is it?

when goto to my code and run this code i see my database

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="126332"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for x in mycursor:
  print(x)
```

**RESULT:**

```
('information_schema',)
('mydatabase',)
('performance_schema',)
('sys',)
('systems',)
```

Comment: [As Barmar asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242126/programmingerror-i-cant-use-my-database-in-python#comment125929268_71242126), are you sure you're connecting to the same server in both instances?

Comment: "You see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global SHOW DATABASES privilege." Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html

Comment: @Chris Fixed yesterday connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

#check database list:

```
    import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for x in mycursor:
  print(x) 

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")
```